# Im getting these errors when Im trying to run Flutter from Visual Studio Code

Tags: flutter

Fix for this?

I have installed Android Studio SDK and I have an AVD file installed so whats the fix?
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hu09W.png

Answer (score 0):

Install flutter and dart plugin for android studio

[android studio](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/editor?tab=androidstudio)

try to run emulator or connect to real device via USB (make sure you enable developer mode enable in real device)

Comment: I;ve done all of those things thats the problem

Comment: can u post result of `flutter doctor -v`